# How can I get count of errors from a mass update in apex

Tags: error-messages

I have an  update in catch try written below.

```
try{
       update acctsToUpdate;
      }catch(Exception e){
        String t = 'Account State Address Update';
        AdminErrorMessage.SendError(e,t);
      }
```

I have a test class that creates a list of errors, but fails because of email limits. I want to see how many error emails will be sent before sending the error message. Or if there is a better method, use that.

The big thing is that I want to avoid getting email limit error when I update this list.

What is the best method? I really don't need the email message on mass updates because, I am the only one that does mass updates, so I will know there is an error and don't need an email, this update clause is on a trigger, not relating to the test class that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use limits method in your test class:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm

I am not sure what kind of limit you are hitting, if it is number of emails/ or maximum invocations etc.. Look it up and adjust the limit numbe. General idea is :

```
if(limits.getEmailInvocations() < 15){
    try{
           update acctsToUpdate;
          }catch(Exception e){
            String t = 'Account State Address Update' + limits.getEmailInvocations() ;
            AdminErrorMessage.SendError(e,t);
          }
    }
```